# Can not run angular on ng serve - Versions of @angular/compiler-cli and typescript could not be determined

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

#### Versions -

```
Angular CLI: 1.7.4
Node: 8.9.4
OS: linux x64
Angular: 4.4.3
... animations, common, compiler, core, forms, http
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

@angular/cdk: 2.0.0-beta.12
@angular/cli: 1.7.4
@angular/compiler-cli: 5.2.9
@angular/language-service: 5.2.9
@angular/material: 2.0.0-beta.12
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.3.2
@angular-devkit/core: 0.5.4
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.3.2
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.2.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.10.2
@schematics/angular: 0.3.2
@schematics/package-update: 0.3.2
typescript: 2.4.2
webpack: 3.11.0
```

#### Package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/common": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/core": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/forms": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/http": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/router": "4.4.3",
    "core-js": "2.5.1",
    "rxjs": "5.4.3",
    "zone.js": "0.8.17",
    "hammerjs": "2.0.8",
    "@angular/cdk": "2.0.0-beta.12",
    "@angular/material": "2.0.0-beta.12",
    "angular2-cool-storage": "^3.0.1",
    "angulartics2": "^2.2.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "cropperjs": "^1.0.0-beta.1",
    "croppie": "^2.4.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "intl": "^1.2.5",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "lato-font": "^2.0.0",
    "material-design-icons": "^3.0.1",
    "mutationobserver-shim": "^0.3.2",
    "ng2-bs3-modal": "^0.10.4",
    "ng2-dnd": "^2.0.1",
    "ng2-file-upload": "^1.1.4-2",
    "ng2-toasty": "^2.3.1",
    "swiper": "^3.4.2",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.2.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^0.5.4",
    "@angular/cli": "^1.7.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.0.4",
    "tslint": "~5.3.2",
    "typescript": "~2.4.2"
  }
```

#### Observed behavior

**ON `ng serve` Command** i am getting this -

> ERROR -
>
> Versions of @angular/compiler-cli and typescript could not be
>   determined. The most common reason for this is a broken npm install.
>
> Please make sure your package.json contains both @angular/compiler-cli
>   and typescript in devDependencies, then delete node_modules and
>   package-lock.json (if you have one) and run npm install again.

I have also try the above mention things and got [**THIS**](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8407#issuecomment-345439010) which i have also tried.

Comment: Did you do what the error message suggested ?

Comment: yes @AdrianFâciu i have tried above things but not worked !! i also get this https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8407#issuecomment-345439010  but version i am using is different.